# Browser window causing script to lock up when Powershell started via *.bat file

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that calls a browser window to select a file. When I run the script in ISE it works correctly. However, when I call it from a batch file opening the browser file causes the script to go non-responsive.
The code I am calling the file with is this.

```
Powershell.exe –ExecutionPolicy Bypass –File “<pile path>”
```

The code for the Brows call is this.

```
$fileBrows = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$null = $fileBrows.ShowDialog()
Return $fileBrows.FileName
```

I have run the as normal and as Administrator, but this make no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add this on top of your code: `[void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( 'System.Windows.Forms' )`

Comment: As aside: **don't use** curly quotes thingies (`“`) in code!

Answer (score 1):

Include `Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms` at the top of your script and try again.

The script should look like this

```
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms
$fileBrows = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$null = $fileBrows.ShowDialog()
Return $fileBrows.FileName
```

Comment: cool! can you mark it as answer and may be upvote the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms` as the example above worked.